# C++ declaring a variable twice

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I am learning about the declaration of variables in C++.

Now please tell me my mistake here. Why is it bad to declare your variable twice?

```
int fly = 0;

for(int fly = 0; fly < 10; fly++) {
    cout << "This is a kite flying" << fly << endl:
}
```

Comment: These are two different variables, because the `for` block creates a new scope.

Comment: Try printing `fly` after the loop and you'll see that it's still `0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are two seperate variable because they are declared in a different [scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm). The scope of a variable is the "area" of code in which it's visible.

As a simple rule of thumb, any place where curly brackets are, or could be placed, is a new scope. The  `fly` inside the for loop, overrides the other `fly`  variable. If it wasn't declared, or declared under a different name. The original variable would still be accessible.